# RDP client with really full screen without any bars

Tags: remote-desktop, fullscreen, dpi

I using RDP client for connect to workstation. My client workstation has 1 screen FullHD 13" with 125% dpi, and 3 other FullHD 24" screens with 100% dpi. Only RDP Client from MS Store can handle this properly, but always is visible some little bar from RDP client. How can I hide this, or exists some other RDP Client with full screen and proper handling various DPI ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the connection bar in full-screen if you uncheck
this option *before* executing the connection:

[image]

Comment: I not using classic RDP Client but RDP client from Microsoft Store. Classic RDP client can't make connection, and set 125% dpi. Or can it, but I don't know how?

Comment: You might want to include that in your question. I have a potential solution but it also uses the classic RDP client

Comment: I already included this.  Please see my post again.

Comment: The Microsoft Store RDP client doesn't have such an option. Perhaps it would be better to post your problem with the classic RDP client to try and solve it.

Comment: @harrymc you are right. I don't know how but I missed desktopscalefactor:i:value parameters in documentation. Now I can set 125% dpi from my client, while connecting to RDP Desktop. But I not closeing this topic, becouse I must test this with many screens in monday (1x 125% dpi screen, and 3x 100% dpi screens).